# Facebook appinvite, how to handle the referral/promo code after user install a new app?

Tags: android, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

With Facebook AppInvite, i want to send invite with an invitation code. But i want that if the user don't have the app installed and if he need to download it first from the play store/app store, then after the first launch of the app, the app must be able to retrieve the invitation code (from referal for example? or delayed deep link?) ...

Is it possible to do so with the facebook SDK ? if yes is their any exact tutorial / sample how to do so ?

I would also like to do the same with facebook share

Comment: Please share if you find a solution.